# Replacing a string in a text field

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column in my database table which has lows of text and lows of rows.  In the text, a url needs to be changed for every row.  In each row the url can exist more than once.

Can I use the replace function to change all the urls in the text field in my database table without affecting the rest of the text in that same column?

Thanks

Comment: what are these urls? is it point to some local resources or to some foreign sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use REPLACE()

```
UPDATE table SET text = REPLACE(text, 'from', 'to')
```

Make precise from: like with http://url_from.com/ to http://url_to.com/

Comment: I doubt all urls are the same

Comment: How would I change that query if the column with the string is col1, and I want to change the string 'hello' to 'bye'?

Comment: If not all are same, than he can use 3rd party functions to regex_replace:
http://www.php-groupies.de/blogs/archives/17-Regular-Expression-Functions-for-MySQL.html

Comment: UPDATE table SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, 'hello', 'bye')

make dump of the table, and test your query till you get proper result ;)

Comment: Yes, i have a test server onto which I replicate the website daily, so any testing it done on the test server before moving onto the live server.

Comment: @oshirowanen if you have all these links the same, you should not store them in the database at all

Answer (score 0):

Based on article posted at https://web.archive.org/web/20150521050102/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-handle-replace-within-an-ntext-column-in-sql-server.html

I needed to write a find and replace for CHAR(146) ` in a text field.  Above article for fort nText and the same solution for text worked with nText with the following changes: 
   -  VARCHAR(32) from nVARCHAR(32)
   -  use @lenOldString = DATALENGTH(@oldString) instead of SET @lenOldString = DATALENGTH(@oldString)/2.

DECLARE
@TextPointer BINARY(16),
@TextIndex INT,
@oldString VARCHAR(32),
@newString VARCHAR(32),
@lenOldString INT,
@currentDataID INT;

SET @oldString = '’';
SET @newString = '''';

IF CHARINDEX(@oldString, @newString) > 0
BEGIN
PRINT 'Quitting to avoid infinite loop.';
END
ELSE
BEGIN

--Need the for nText fields
--SET @lenOldString = DATALENGTH(@oldString)/2

--Use this for text fields
SET @lenOldString = DATALENGTH(@oldString)

DECLARE irows CURSOR
LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT
DataID
FROM
dbo.tbData
WHERE
PATINDEX('%'+@oldString+'%', TextData) > 0;

OPEN irows;

FETCH NEXT FROM irows INTO @currentDataID;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

SELECT
@TextPointer = TEXTPTR(TextData),
@TextIndex = PATINDEX('%'+@oldString+'%', TextData)
FROM
dbo.tbData
WHERE
DataID = @currentDataID;

SELECT @TextPointer, @TextIndex

WHILE
(
SELECT
PATINDEX('%'+@oldString+'%', TextData)
FROM
dbo.tbData
WHERE
DataID = @currentDataID
) > 0
BEGIN

SELECT
@TextIndex = PATINDEX('%'+@oldString+'%', TextData)-1
FROM
dbo.tbData
WHERE
DataID = @currentDataID;

UPDATETEXT dbo.tbData.TextData @TextPointer @TextIndex @lenOldString @newString;
END
FETCH NEXT FROM irows INTO @currentDataID;
END

CLOSE irows;
DEALLOCATE irows;

END